# Problems with migration from older ruby/rbenv

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rake, octopress

I faced with the following problem:
I update my OS X to Yosemite, switched to ruby 2.2.2 and decided to come back to my Octopress-based blog. Below I try to describe all my actions one by one, will be glad if someone tell me where I did something wrong.
So I cloned my page from [github](https://github.com/KirillLykov/kirilllykov.github.com) , checkout to source branch. But when I try to execute any rake command I get error:

```
rbenv: version `1.9.3-p194' is not installed
rbenv: version `1.9.3-p194' is not installed
```

I did:

```
> rbenv local --unset
> rake reharsh --trace
rake aborted!
LoadError: cannot load such file -- bundler/setup
MYPATH/Rakefile:2:in `<top (required)>'
```

Thus I install bundler:

```
> gem install bundler
> bundle install
Fetching gem metadata from http://rubygems.org/...........
Fetching version metadata from http://rubygems.org/...
Fetching dependency metadata from http://rubygems.org/..
Installing rake 0.9.2.2
etc
```

Finally:

```
> rake generate --trace
rake aborted!
Gem::LoadError: You have already activated rake 10.4.2, but your Gemfile requires rake 0.9.2.2. Prepending `bundle exec` to your command may solve this.
```

UPD: Following advices of K M Rakibul Islam, I changed in the `gemfile` rake version from 0.9.2 to 10.4 and added line `gem 'iconv'` to the gem file. After that `rake generate` start working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the error message suggests, you should run the rake command using `bundle exec` in order to run it in the context of your `Gemfile`:

```
bundle exec rake generate --trace
```

This should fix your issue.

#### Update

change this: `gem 'rake', '~> 0.9.2'` to `gem 'rake', '~> 10.4.2'` in your `Gemfile` and run: `bundle install`.

Comment: Am I right that in this case I will use older version of rake?

Comment: whatever version you have in your `Gemfile`, using bundle exec, you will be using that version. But, I think you should just update your rake gem: `bundle update rake`, because you have a really old version of the rake gem in your `Gemfile`

Comment: I tried to do that but it only updates a little - saying `Installing rake 0.9.6 (was 0.9.2.2)` instead of 10.x

Comment: change this: `gem 'rake', '~> 0.9.2'` to `gem 'rake', '~> 10.4.2'` and then try again.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95510/discussion-between-k-m-rakibul-islam-and-kirill-lykov).